# How to remove this bottom bar in UITabBar or UITabBatViewController?

Tags: ios5, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am trying to do some customization on UITabBar.  I am almost done with everything.  However, I saw a small bar on the bottom of each UITabBarItem.  I don't know what object it is.  Can someone please tell me how to remove it?  Or if someone can tell me how to make the UIImage inside the UITabBarItem to be displayed in front of that unknown bar.  It is good enough.

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s214/sh/a3f42cea-a36e-449e-bf91-83f82c82a32f/8f3c35eb158008f96d0d4f5f621d7ff4

Color blended layers mode
http://www.evernote.com/shard/s214/sh/3d506d1b-6159-429e-952a-f2cdeb270c56/6c747156a612ea74205724ec1441942a

I have a custom UITabBarViewController and UITabBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No solution can be done using the default tab controller.  I just recreate the custom tab controller.

Answer (score 0):

> Please select View based Application.
>   In Tabbar Application , the default tab bar will be appeared at bottom.

Comment: Are you referring the XCode?  How can I do it if I am using the story board?